# How to insert timestamp without timezone using Supabase-JS client?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase

I want to insert current timestamp without timezone to Supabase.

- I know I can set default value of the timestamp column to `NOW()` but
  there can be some delay in the timing and I need it precise.
- I have tried `Date.now()` but got the error: `date/time field value   out of range`

*How can this be done?*

Answer (score 6):

You can insert the time from javascript by setting

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

when doing an insert or update. I want to address the first part of your statement though as the precise time is the time that data hits the server so having `NOW()` as the default value in Postgres is more accurate than you passing the date over the wire in my opinion.